# Intellij time spend in a specific method

Tags: intellij-idea, time

have this question is there a possibility on Intellij (Ultimate edition) to check how much seconds program spends in specific method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't.

If I need just a quick, simple number for a single method while in development, then I insert System.nanoTime() at the start and at the end of the method and log out the delta.

For more involved profiling I use YourKit - it is commercial, but there is a free evaluation version that is not restricted feature-wise. It also comes with a nice IDEA plugin, so that you can start your application as usual.

You could also try Java's hprof option, but I find that to be complicated and not granular enough.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I know about nanoTime and other things, just needed to check maybe intellij has something in it.